# break an URL in the source file

Tags: line-breaking, url

I would like to break the url of the command

```
\href{https://www.nature.com/nature-research/editorial-policies/reporting-standards#data}
            {policies}
```

in the source file as follows:

```
\href{https://
      www.nature.com/
      nature-
      research/
      editorial-
      policies/
      reporting-
      standards#
      data}
      {policies}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the URL to be linkable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to have understood well your question. Something as this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\sloppy
\url{https://
      www.nature.com/
      nature-
      research/
      editorial-
      policies/
      reporting-
      standards#
      datapolicies}
\end{document}
```

or this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\sloppy
\url{https://
      www.nature.com/
      nature-
      research/
      editorial-
      policies/
      reporting-
      standards#
      data}

\noindent \url{policies}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. In my question only "policies" appears in the PDF, pointing to the page determined by the URL. However, when trying to split another link with the url command (http://www.nature.com/authors/policies/ BREAK data/data-availability-statements-data-citations.pdf), then the link is dead due to an extra space.

Comment: @TobiR The solution exist I think. If you edit your question and you can explain as you want break a long link surely other users can give you an answer.