# break an URL in \href command

Tags: url, href

I would like to break an URL in my source file, using the `\href` command as follows:

```
\href{http://www.nature.com/authors/policies/
      data/data-availability-statements-data-citations.pdf}
 {data availibility}
```

where "data availibility" should appear in the PDF file, bearing (pointing to) the underlying URL. I tried using the `\sloppy` command, but the link is dead due to an extra whitespace.
Could you please help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Simply omit the line break in the url ...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529047/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\href{http://www.nature.com/authors/policies/%
data/data-availability-statements-data-citations.pdf}%
{data availibility}
```

Does this solve your problem?

You can't have a space between the curly brackets or in this URL, as this is not a way either the command or the URL can be recognized. `%` makes LaTeX ignore the space.

Alternatively, `\href{http://www.nature.com/authors/policies/data/data-availability-statements-data-citations.pdf}{data availibility}` would be the standard way to go about this.

Comment: You can't suppress spaces with % in an url.

Comment: But the line break seems to be ignored in this href here, for me the hyperref works with % in this example, and doesn't without %.

Comment: Hm. You are right, it actually ignores the one at the end.