# Is there a way to force the BiBTeX interpreter to ignore a linebreak in the source document?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I wanted to clean up my `literature.bib` file and sort all equal signs below each other.
As my editor is set to a width of only 81 characters I frequently have to add line breaks in the different fields.
This is no problem at all for fields like author, title or journal. But I get a problem when I want to add a line break into urls. The compiled link name is displayed correctly but **the hyper link gets an extra space** where the line break in my .bib file is.

```
@article{ Author:Year,
    author         = "A. Smith and J. Doe and M. Williams and D. Brown and
                      V. Johnson and H. Garcia"
    title          = "{Some very interesting publication with a much too long
                       title that ever would fit into one line}",
    journal        = "Journal This and That: with special focus on a lot of
                      different topics",
    url            = "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554257/
                      is-there-a-way-to-force-the-tex-interpreter-to-ignore-a-
                      linebreak-in-the-source"
}
```

Resulting link name would be correct:
`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554257/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-tex-interpreter-to-ignore-a-linebreak-in-the-source`
But the hyper link would forward to the non existing (**because of the two spaces**):
`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554257/ is-there-a-way-to-force-the-tex-interpreter-to-ignore-a- linebreak-in-the-source`

This is only cosmetics, of course. But any change to get this working?
I tried already with a backspace to escape the newline but this did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: your title is a bit misleading as the answer for tex is yes, but you need bibtex not tex to ignore the line breaks and that is a different question

Comment: you can end the lines of the url with %. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529431/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : that worked straight away. Thank you very much!